# Getting connection timeout to URL, which I'm otherwise able to connect via browser in the same system

Tags: java, networking, java-8, connection, httpurlconnection

Due to company policies, I cannot share the complete code here, but here is where the code fails:

```
try(InputStream in = new URL("URL with image file").openStream()){
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get("file://newfile.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

The Exception is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

The things I have tried:

1. Adding proxy and port number before openstream method
2. Adding User agent
3. Using system proxy settings

Note: I'm trying to save an image from the URL. I have tried accessing the URL with my personal system and it's working. With my company system, it's not, even after adding the proxy.

Could someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: What happens if you use `curl` to access that URL? If you add the `--verbose` option, you might get some useful clues. Your code seems fine.. I used [this img url](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/--XA3iMvaJLY/Tw_GykPs-eI/AAAAAAAAEgU/EmFKS7Cz5xQ/s1600/Duck-04.jpg), and changed the "path" statement to this: `Paths.get("/tmp/newfile.png")` and it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry, it was a dumb mistake on my part. I put https in the proxy setting. I have updated my post. Thank You for the help!

Comment: Good news. Thanks for posting the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was my mistake. If anyone is seeing this:

The problem came from how I used proxy. If you are NOT able to connect to a website which is otherwise accessible via browser **in same system**, then you need a proxy in your java code.

For example:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80));
```

Hope this helps. If you have any doubts regarding this, I'll be happy to help.

*Note*: **Don't use "https" for proxy. Give only domain name.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).